# Stored procedure to return data based on sum of 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure as follows:

```
SELECT   DiscountId
        ,CompanyId
        ,Discount1
        ,Discount2
        ,Discount3  
        ,(Discount1+Discount2+Discount3) as Total
FROM PriceDiscount
```

This can return one or more rows.

I also need to check the aggregate of Discount1, Discount2 and Discount3. If the **sum** for any of the rows is greater than 0, I want to set a column `isDiscounted = true` and return it also.

Please help me - how can I achieve this?

I do not want to check this in the code or create another stored procedure for this. Hence wanted to return both the results from this stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case` to calculate/set the `isDiscounted` column.

```
with x as (
SELECT DiscountId
    ,CompanyId
    ,Discount1
    ,Discount2
    ,Discount3  
    ,case when (Discount1+Discount2+Discount3) > 0 then 'True'
     else 'False' end  as isDiscounted
FROM PriceDiscount)
, y as (select case when isDiscounted = 'True' then count(*) end as true_count,
               case when isDiscounted = 'False' then count(*) end as false_count
        from x group by isDiscounted)
select case when true_count > 0 then 'True'
            when falsecount > 0 and truecount = 0 then 'False' end
       as final_status
from y
```

Edit:

```
with x as (
SELECT DiscountId
    ,CompanyId
    ,Discount1
    ,Discount2
    ,Discount3  
    ,case when (Discount1+Discount2+Discount3) > 0 then 'True'
     else 'False' end  as isDiscounted
FROM PriceDiscount)
, y as (select sum(case when isDiscounted = 'True' then 1 else 0 end) as true_count,
               sum(case when isDiscounted = 'False' then 1 else 0 end) as false_count 
        from x)
select case when true_count > 0 then 'True'
            when false_count > 0 and true_count = 0 then 'False' end
       as final_status
from y
```

Comment: But this would set each row to either true or false. I finally want to check that if there is a single true, return true. If discount1+discount2+discount3 for all the rows is 0, then return false. If any of the rows has discount1+discount2+discount3 >0, return true.

Comment: @vkp.Thanks for the answer. But there are instances when instead of just a true or false, I get final_status as:
NULL
True                                                                                                                 Can you tell me why this happens?

Comment: yes..you would have to do one more cte to take the max of true and false counts to eliminate that..i ll post it shortly